# Using sed or awk to format a column of bssids

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a 1.5GB file of data formatted almost the way I want, but I need to convert the BSSID's to a more MAC address readable format.

My input data looks like this:

```
id,data_source,bssid,lat,lon,range,updated,created
1155506572,-1,0037B78D708D,45.77844080,4.80769845,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506595,-1,F4CAE5E78AD4,45.78175649,4.81046725,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506641,-1,18622CACD9BC,45.76656373,4.81941711,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506661,-1,4883C72CC295,45.78551839,4.81023433,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506677,-1,000B3BD19CAF,45.77941868,4.80828591,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506696,-1,0007CB08471D,45.76691825,4.82602490,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
id,data_source,bssid,lat,lon,range,updated,created
1155506572,-1,00:37:B7:8D:70:8D,45.77844080,4.80769845,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506595,-1,F4:CA:E5:E7:8A:D4,45.78175649,4.81046725,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506641,-1,18:62:2C:AC:D9:BC,45.76656373,4.81941711,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506661,-1,48:83:C7:2C:C2:95,45.78551839,4.81023433,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506677,-1,00:0B:3B:D1:9C:AF,45.77941868,4.80828591,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506696,-1,00:07:CB:08:47:1D,45.76691825,4.82602490,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
  awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR>1  {n=split($3,a,""); 
              $3=a[1]a[2]; 
              for(i=3;i<n;i+=2) $3=$3":"a[i]a[i+1]}1' file

id,data_source,bssid,lat,lon,range,updated,created
1155506572,-1,00:37:B7:8D:70:8D,45.77844080,4.80769845,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506595,-1,F4:CA:E5:E7:8A:D4,45.78175649,4.81046725,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506641,-1,18:62:2C:AC:D9:BC,45.76656373,4.81941711,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506661,-1,48:83:C7:2C:C2:95,45.78551839,4.81023433,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506677,-1,00:0B:3B:D1:9C:AF,45.77941868,4.80828591,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506696,-1,00:07:CB:08:47:1D,45.76691825,4.82602490,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
```

Comment: You should mention that's non-portable since it relies on undefined behavior per POSIX (splitting with a null string as the separator causing the string to be split into characters). It'll work in GNU awk and maybe some others though.

Comment: awesome, thanks, that worked amazing!  awk is great!!

Answer (score 0):

OR

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1{$3=substr($3,1,2) ":" substr($3,3,2) ":" substr($3,5,2) ":" substr($3,7,2) ":" substr($3,9,2) ":" substr($3,11,2)}1' file

id,data_source,bssid,lat,lon,range,updated,created
1155506572,-1,00:37:B7:8D:70:8D,45.77844080,4.80769845,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506595,-1,F4:CA:E5:E7:8A:D4,45.78175649,4.81046725,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506641,-1,18:62:2C:AC:D9:BC,45.76656373,4.81941711,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506661,-1,48:83:C7:2C:C2:95,45.78551839,4.81023433,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506677,-1,00:0B:3B:D1:9C:AF,45.77941868,4.80828591,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506696,-1,00:07:CB:08:47:1D,45.76691825,4.82602490,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
```

IHTH

Comment: would be interested to know the results of `time awk ...` between the two versions (run each 2 X to eliminate changes due to caching). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{gsub(/../,"&:",$3); sub(/:$/,"",$3)} 1' file
id,data_source,bssid,lat,lon,range,updated,created
1155506572,-1,00:37:B7:8D:70:8D,45.77844080,4.80769845,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506595,-1,F4:CA:E5:E7:8A:D4,45.78175649,4.81046725,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506641,-1,18:62:2C:AC:D9:BC,45.76656373,4.81941711,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506661,-1,48:83:C7:2C:C2:95,45.78551839,4.81023433,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506677,-1,00:0B:3B:D1:9C:AF,45.77941868,4.80828591,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
1155506696,-1,00:07:CB:08:47:1D,45.76691825,4.82602490,140.00,1469833291,1469833291
```